# try_files redirecting instead of using fallback directory?

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, reverse-proxy

I'm running an nginx SPA application.However for requests I would like a fallback/fallthrough approach:

I have the main directory `/` which has the main `/index.html` as well as "default"  icons. However it also contains a subdirectory `/local/` which contains (potentially) values from the default directory - overwriting those existing ones. (This is to allow a docker volume, to provide specific favicon.ico etc from the host OS and modify that without rebuilding the docker).

Initially I had the following proxy directive:

```
root /var/www/html;
location / {
    # redirect everything to show the main SPA application
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires 7d;
}
location = /index.html { }
```

Which works, however it does not prefer the files under `/local` unless specified in the request.

I then tried to add a longer try_files list:

```
root /var/www/html;
location / {
    # redirect everything to show the main SPA application
    try_files $uri/local $uri/local/ $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires 7d;
}
location = /index.html { }
```

However now if I go to the mainpage `localhost:80` a redirect (301) to `localhost//local/` happens

I feel I do not understand the try_files function. And secondly I wonder how above can be done. In summary this is the lookup I wish nginx to do (notice no redirection for frontend):

```
localhost/ => ./index.html
localhost/favicon.ico => ./local/favicon.ico //IF that file exists
localhost/favicon.ico => ./favicon.ico //IF ./local/favicon does not exist
localhost/unexistingfile => ./index.html
```

How would I do this? Or is this impossible at nginx level and should I do this in the application layer?

Comment: I think you should be using `/local$uri` and not `$uri/local`. Also, `$uri/local/` is generating the 301 - any file parameter that ends with a `/` will generate a 301 if the path resolves to a local directory.

Comment: @RichardSmith what's the `$uri/` then doing?

Comment: That one is also looking for directories, but it will not respond to `localhost:80`. You would need to specify a directory in the original request, for example  `localhost:80/local` might generate a 301 redirect to `localhost:80/local/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith the first comment is actually the solution, removing $uri/local/ together with the `/local$uri` instead of `$uri/local`. If you make a post from it I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the request `//localhost/favicon.ico`, the value of `$uri` is set to `/favicon.ico`.

The file term `$uri/local` will cause Nginx to search for a file at `/var/www/html/favicon.ico/local`, which is **not** your intent.

The correct file term is `/local$uri`, which will cause Nginx to search for a file at `/var/www/html/local/favicon.ico`.

---

From [the `try_files` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

> It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at
> the end of a name

When Nginx finds a directory using `try_files` in this way, it issues an **external redirection** to a URL with a trailing `/`. URLs with a trailing `/` that resolve to a directory are then processed by [the index module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index).

Your file term `$uri/local/` is matching the directory `/var/www/html/local` for the `//localhost` request, which causes the unwanted redirection to `//localhost/local/`.

---

In summary, use:

```
try_files /local$uri $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

First, the file term `/local$uri` will look for files under the `local` subdirectory.

Second, the file term `$uri` will look for files starting from the root.

Third, the file term `$uri/` will perform normal index processing where the URL resolves to a directory.

The final parameter is a URI, which causes Nginx to generate an **internal redirection** to `index.html` if none of the file terms found a match.